# Combination and Permutation How many words can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A contest consists of finding all code words that can be formed from the letters in the word "alpha".Assume that the letter "a" can be used twice but the others at most once:

a)How many five-letter words can be formed?

5*4*3=60 words

b)How many two-letter words can be formed?

with two letter words can be formed is 13

c)How many  words can be formed?

5 letter words=60
4 letter words=60
3 letter words=33
2 letter words=13
1 letter words=4
so,60+60+33+13+4=170

Could you please check t for me?

Comment: a), b) correct. c) wrong (check 4 letter words).

Comment: How come a) is correct? You choose 2 slots for a and then 3! for the remaining lettetrs

Comment: @Alex You can also choose where to place the l, the p, and the h, then place the two a's in the two open positions.

Comment: Yes of course; i'm not sure why i wrote it